# Lua, is this possible?

Tags: lua

I am working on a game using love2d and i haven't quite programmed in lua. Not sure on technical wording so i'll post my code and explain what i'm trying to do:

```
item = {}
item.stat = {}
player.x = 100
player.y = 100
-- 
item[0].stat.damage = 10
```

What i'm trying to do is make an inventory system and an item database. I want to be able to make the item database with the code above so i could add an item like so:

```
item[1].stat.damage = 10
item[1].stat.speed = 10
item[2].stat.damage = 20
item[2].stat.speed = 5
--
player.inventory[0] = item[1]
player.inventory[1] = item[2]
```

can someone tell me what coding principle this may so i can research it? I basically want to make a matrix that i can access like above while having the convenience of named arrays instead of saying `item[1,"damage"] = 10`

Edit:

I realise now i can do item.stat.damage[1] = 10 but i have to setup an array for each one, is there an easier way?

Comment: Tables are Lua's only data structure. It is the easiest way. Anything else is inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use tables:

```
player = {}
player.x = 100
print(player.x)  -- prints 100
```

Note that `player.x` is simply syntactic sugar for `player["x"]`, so the following lines are equivalent:

```
print(player.x)     -- prints 100
print(player["x"])  -- also prints 100
```

With that in mind, you could construct your game data like this for example:

```
item = {}
item[1] = {}
item[1].stat = {}
item[1].stat.damage = 10
item[1].stat.speed = 10
item[2] = {}
item[2].stat = {}
item[2].stat.damage = 20
item[2].stat.speed = 5

player = {}
player.x = 100
player.y = 100
player.inventory = {}
player.inventory[1] = item[1]
player.inventory[2] = item[2]

print(player.inventory[2].stat.damage)           -- prints 20
print(player["inventory"][2]["stat"]["damage"])  -- equivalent, also prints 20
```

It is probably a good idea to define functions that create items or players and automatically set all the required fields.

Eventually, you may want to use actual [classes and objects](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientedProgramming) (for example, if you want to define methods on your objects).

**EDIT:**

Here is the example from above with functions `create_item`, `create_player` to create items or players. I've used [named parameters](https://www.lua.org/pil/5.3.html) for these functions so one doesn't have to remember the order of the function parameters (note the curly braces when calling the functions).

```
function create_item(arg)
    local item = {}
    item.stat = {}
    item.stat.damage = arg.damage
    item.stat.speed = arg.speed
    return item
end

function create_player(arg)
    local player = {}
    player.x = arg.x
    player.y = arg.y
    player.inventory = {}
    return player
end

item = {}
item[1] = create_item{damage=10, speed=10}
item[2] = create_item{damage=20, speed=5}

player = create_player{x=100, y=100}
player.inventory[1] = item[1]
player.inventory[2] = item[2]

print(player.inventory[2].stat.damage)           -- prints 20
print(player["inventory"][2]["stat"]["damage"])  -- equivalent, also prints 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always shorten your code:

```
item = {
    stat = {},
    [0] = { stat = { damage = 10 } },
    [1] = { stat = { damage = 10, speed = 10 } },
    [2] = { stat = { damage = 20, speed = 5 } },
}
player = { x = 100, y = 100, inventory = { [0] = item[1], [1] = item[2] } }
```

You can access that code in matrix way like

```
function item:getstat(index, param)
    return self[index] and self[index].stat and self[index].stat[param];
end

function item:setstat(index, param, value)
    local t1 = self[index]
    if (t1 == nil) then
        t1 = {}
        self[index] = t1
    end
    local t2 = t1.stat
    if (t2 == nil) then
        t2 = {}
        t1.stat = t2
    end
    t2[param] = value
end


print(item:getstat(0, "damage"))
item:setstat(1, "speed", 20)
```